# Rows disappearing after closing sql application

Tags: sql, oracle

Rows are persistently deleted after closing sql command line and connecting again  .
**Important observation -Data is not appearing in Oracle object browser after insertion query from sql command line**.
*Oracle database 10g express edition*

After Connecting to User -

```
Insert into Block_User values(21,'sdaa');

->1 row created.

select * from Block_User;

  ->  id  Name

      21 sdaa
  


After Closing sql application and launching ,connecting again-

select * from Block_User;

->no rows selected .
```

Comment: You probably need to `commit` your transactions.

Comment: [commit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html#GUID-6CD5C9A7-54B9-4FA2-BA3C-D6B4492B9EE2)

Comment: Thanks alot @GordonLinoff ,sorry  for asking  such basic question i am pretty naive to database .

Comment: Oracle database 10g express edition is pretty old, there's an 11 and 18 version of this available today if you're game to get your hands on newer tech.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith there are also 12 and 19 :)

Comment: @VBokšić no, there is no 12c XE or 19c XE, which is why i mentioned 11 and 18

Answer (score 0):

After Insert:

```
Insert into Block_User values(21,'sdaa');
```

provide `commit;` so that it will make the permanent changes to the transaction and your changes will not get lost.

For information you can check the below link:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/commit_statement.htm